# jQuery not working on site, but works on jsfiddle

Tags: jquery

The following code put together by stefanz works great on jsfiddle, but I cannot get it working on my local wordpress site..

Here is the fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/9ae3T/

Here is the code:

```
<ul class="tabs js-view-mode">
  <li><a href="#list">List</a></li>
  <li><a href="#grid">Grid</a></li>
  <li><a href="#full">Full</a></li>
</ul>

<section id="viewMode">
  <div id="list">here is list mode content</div>
  <div id="grid">here is grid mode content</div>
  <div id="full">here is full mode content</div>
</section>


$(document).ready(function(){
  var wrap = $('#viewMode'),
      viewMode = $.cookie( 'view-mode' );
  wrap.children().hide();

  $('.js-view-mode').on( 'click', 'a',function( e ){
    e.preventDefault();
    var t = $(this),
        type = t.attr('href');

    $(type).fadeIn()
      .siblings().fadeOut();

    viewMode = $.cookie( 'view-mode', type );

  });

  if ( viewMode ) {
    $('.js-view-mode a[href='+ viewMode +']').trigger('click');
  } else {
    $('.js-view-mode li:first a').trigger( 'click' );
  }

});
```

Does anyone have a suggestion? This is what I have in my head (viewmode.js is the above code):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') ?>/js/viewmode.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') ?>/js/cookie.js"></script>


        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i guess it is because it is causing the conflict..try to use `jQuery` instead of `$` or use jquery no conflict

Comment: That did the trick!! After hours of brain bleeding frustration, thats all I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Include jQuery *before* including your own file as it obviously uses jQuery.

*Also I hope you realise that you can't put HTML in a `.js` file.*

Comment: Good point, but that didn't do the trick. Any other reasons why it might not be working?

Comment: No more ideas. It's time for you to open Developer Console (Ctrl+Shift+C in Chrome) and look for errors.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I needed noconflict

Answer (score 1):

You are loding is your **javascript files** before **jQuery** which is a hard dependency..

Include jQuery first and then your files.

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
 // include jQuery First
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" 
     src="<?php echo bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') ?>/js/viewmode.js">
</script>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" 
     src="<?php echo bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') ?>/js/cookie.js">
</script>
```